# Have several Firebase Cloud Functions repos on one computer (different Firebase projects)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I used Firebase Cloud Functions for a previous project and would now like to use it in a different Firebase project. I created a second folder in which I initialized Firebase ("firebase init").

However, during the installation, a warning tells me that package.json already exists. It looks like it is reading the other project's folder, and trying to re-use it or overwrite it.

Is it possible to have several different folders on the same computer, one for each of my Firebase projects (same Firebase account)? Is it best-practice and if not, is there another preferred way?

**Update**

Current folder structure:

./Development/functions (previous project)

./Development/functions-newproject (in which I try to init firebase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple projects, but when you go to initialize a project, Firebase will look in the current directory and any parent directories for `.firebaserc`. That file is how the Firebase CLI knows which project it is in. So as long as the directory you're creating the project in isn't a subdirectory of an existing project, you can create another project.

Comment: Makes sense! I updated my question adding my folder structure and indeed, it looks like I should have created a Development/functions-project1 and init the first project inside that subfolder. PS: One moment I am watching your great tutorial videos, the next you are helping me on SO! Amazing... Thanks Jen!